# how to sort an array of objects based on any one its atributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of Objects as below.

```
options: [
          {value: 1, label: "test1"},
          {value: 2, label: "test12"},
          {value: 0, label: "test123"}
         ]
```

I want to sort this array based on `value` property of the object. please let me know can I achieve it in Javascript.

Comment: Maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48942106/1641941) will help. Let me know if you need more help (don't forget to start with @...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use sort like this:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let data =  [
    {value: 1, label: "test1"},
    {value: 2, label: "test12"},
    {value: 0, label: "test123"}
];

data.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: `data.sort((direction => (a, b) => (a.value - b.value)*direction)(-1));` for descending and `data.sort((direction => (a, b) => (a.value - b.value)*direction)(1));` for ascending order. I usually refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48942106/1641941) for composing a sorter function.

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort`

```js
let options = [{
    value: 1,
    label: "test1"
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: "test12"
  },
  {
    value: 0,
    label: "test123"
  }
]

options.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

console.log(options);
```

Doc: [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)